# how to show admin/reports/dblog in terminal ( cli )

Tags: log-messages

While developing I really like a dedicated screen with all the drupal log messages.
Working on mac or *nix creating a new terminal window and doing a tail -f on the log file would be really nice. So I can do a tail -f on the apache error.log but I want to show the drupal log that is shown in admin/reports/dblog
Where can I find it and or is it possible to let it output to a terminal screen and if so how?

Comment: @dinesh thanks for the tags! That where the exact tags I would create but missing 19 rep ;)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) to do this:

```
$ drush help | grep watchdog
 watchdog-delete       Delete watchdog messages.
 watchdog-list         Show available message types and severity levels. A
 (wd-list)             prompt will ask for a choice to show watchdog messages.
 watchdog-show         Show watchdog messages.
```

`drush watchdog-show` has too many options to fully show here, but these are the examples:

```
 drush watchdog-show                       Show a listing of most recent 10
                                           messages.
 drush watchdog-show 64                    Show in detail message with id 64.
 drush watchdog-show "cron run succesful"  Show a listing of most recent 10
                                           messages containing the string "cron
                                           run succesful".
 drush watchdog-show --count=46            Show a listing of most recent 46
                                           messages.
 drush watchdog-show --severity=notice     Show a listing of most recent 10
                                           messages with a severity of notice.
 drush watchdog-show --type=php            Show a listing of most recent 10
                                           messages of type php.
 drush watchdog-tail                       Show a listing of most recent 10
                                           messages and continue showing messages
                                           as they are registered in the watchdog.
```

Comment: Thanks `drush watchdog-show --tail --full --count=50` is what I'm using now :)

Comment: The alias is `drush ws`, which is quick to type.

Answer (score 3):

You have to enable the Syslog module, and the log will be available in /var/log/drupal.log. For more information, you can read [Syslog: OS-integrated logging](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/syslog).