# How can I output log messages to stdout/stderr?

Tags: 8, log-messages

I can create log messages really easily in `Drupal 9.x` like this;

```
\Drupal::logger('mymodule')->error("something went wrong");
```

I see these messages appear in `/admin/reports/dblog`, but it would be convenient if I had the option to print them to stdout, or perhaps a file that I could `tail`. Is this possible?

Note that this question looks similar but I think it's for an older version of drupal using `watchdog`, so I don't think it applies: [how to show admin/reports/dblog in terminal ( cli )](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48645/how-to-show-admin-reports-dblog-in-terminal-cli)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’ve been using the [log_stdout](https://www.drupal.org/project/log_stdout) module for stdout logging. It works well with Docker containers.

> This module provides a hook for Drupal Watchdog that directs log messages to `php://stdout` or `php://stderr` for better log handling with [Docker](https://www.docker.com/).